# How to Omit a property from a type with an index signature

Tags: typescript

I have a type with some fixed properties and an index signature for any other properties. The type represents an API response where the types of some properties are known in advance whilst others could be multiple types.

Here is a simplified example of the type:

```
export declare type TypeA = {
    prop1?: string;
    prop2?: number;
    prop3?: boolean;
    [key: string]: string | number | boolean | undefined;
};
```

This works perfectly. When I access prop1 it's `string | undefined` prop2 is `number | undefined` etc. When accessing any other prop such as `prop4` it's typed as `string | number | boolean | undefined` which is exactly what I want.

Now consider a second type where I Omit a single property from `TypeA`

```
type TypeB = Omit<TypeA, "prop2">;
```

When using this new type every property is typed as `string | number | boolean | undefined` including the properties that have explicit types such as `prop1`.

If the index signature is removed the `Omit` works as expected.

Why does using Omit strip the types from the explicitly typed properties in TypeA?

Comment: I’m sure this question has been answered before but I think nowadays you’d use key remapping to get it done.  If nobody else answers this by the time I get to a real computer I’ll do so.

Comment: ^ That would look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5z6Zm).